# why the html.erb are not called html.rb?

Tags: ruby

I mean what is the difference between erb and rb? I thought erb after and html was simply a way to say, hey this is an HTML but used "inside" a ruby directory of several files and subdirectories

Answer (score 5):

`erb` is the extension of the [template engine](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) used to interpret the file.

In Rails, the filename determines the template engine used to parse and interpret a file. For instance, `style.scss` is processed by the SCSS template engine. Likewise, `script.coffee.erb` is processed by ERB, and the result is processed by CoffeeScript template engine.

Extensions are just conventions. You can easily call a file `hello.txt` and feed it to the Ruby interpreter. The interpreter will happily execute it as any other Ruby script. It doesn't have to be called `hello.rb`.

Comment: I would elaborate on this to point out that in Rails, you can also write extensions with other template engines like Haml or Slim, so you could have `html.haml` and `html.slim` files, and the extension lets Rails know which template engine to use. If it was just `html.rb` it would be logical to try to interpret it as a Ruby script, which is it not.

Comment: It should be `style.css.scss` and `script.js.coffee.erb`

Answer (score 2):

erb is the file extension for eRuby documents, which is a way of embedding Ruby into a text document. Similar to how PHP works. rb is the file extension for ruby scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The eruby language is not compatible with Ruby; the entire file written in eruby cannot be interpreted by a Ruby interpreter (although fragments of it are Ruby scripts). eruby and Ruby are different languages. Since the convention is that the extension expresses the language a file is written in, file written respective languages have different extensions.